# C# Menu Control places an arrow that is beyond the menu item

Tags: c#, css, menu

I have created a menu control. There are main menu items and then static items. The menu control places a default arrow head pointing to the right. I wanted to change the direction, pointing downwards and also, it seems like the default menu control creates a separate td for the placement of the arrow. I didn't like this, because this actually places the arrow beyond the menu item.

So I disabled the default arrow and added my own.

```
// Create a new Menu control.
    _MainNav = new Menu();
    _MainNav.StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage = false;
    _MainNav.DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage = false;
    _MainNav.StaticPopOutImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Images/Arrow.png";
    _MainNav.DynamicPopOutImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Images/Arrow.png";
```

This fixed the direction of the arrow. From pointing to the right, now it points downwards.

However the arrow is still placed in a new td.... there is a gap between the menu item and the arrow indicating that there are child items. Visually it looks like that the arrow for one of the menu item is placed at the beginning of the next menu item.

[image]

Here is my css:-

```
div.nav
{
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 960px;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
    clear: both;
}

.menu
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #71cd7b;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.menu tr
{
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}
.menu td
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu td a
{
    float: left;
    width: 134px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-indent: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-image: url(Images/divider.jpg);
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
.menu td a:hover
{
    background-color: #7156a4;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.menu td a.active
{
    background-color: #7156a4;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.subMenu
{
    border:1px double Black;   
    border-width: thin;
}

.subMenuItem
{
    background-color : white;
    width: 160px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-family:@Arial Unicode MS;
    color:Black;
}

.subMenuItem:hover
{
    background-color :#7156a4;   
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:White;
}
```

My HTML:-

```
<div id="nav" class="nav">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="MenuPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="body_block">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
```

How can I move the arrow back a little bit to the left so that it falls in the same section of the menu and not at the beginning of the next section.

Comment: Sorry, what method did you use to add the arrow?

Comment: Can we get the output HTML as well?

Comment: I used C#'s Menu control.

Comment: I also added the HTML where I place my menu.